# Indexing the prefix of a varchar

Tags: mysql, performance, indexing, varchar, prefix

I have a 20 Million records table that has this column:
category_value varchar(4000).

I also have an index on this column, but still get bad results:

```
mysql> select count(*) from daniel_table where category_value like 'giraffe%'; 
+----------+ 
| count(*) | 
+----------+ 
| 107130 | 
+----------+ 
1 row in set (2 min 4.33 sec)
```

So what i did, is created a new field -
Short_value varchar(32)
Which contains-  Substr(category_value, 1, 32)
And of course has an index.

Now, when i search this field its better:

```
mysql> select count(*) from daniel_table where short_value like 'giraffe%'; 
+----------+ 
| count(*) | 
+----------+ 
| 107130 | 
+----------+ 
1 row in set (1.36 sec)
```

However, I don't want to create a new field, it's duplicate.

I tried creating this index on the original varchar(4000):
key cat32(category_value(32))

And got this result:

```
mysql> select count(*) from daniel_table use index (cat32) where Category_Value like 'giraffe%' ;
+----------+
| count(*) |
+----------+
|   107130 |
+----------+
1 row in set (24.60 sec)
```

Which is still bad performance comparing to the varchar(32) field.
When looking into this a little bit I've figured out the problem.
As you can see in the explain, there is no "using index" in the extra field.
Meaning, Mysql fetch the table for each row its found.
Why does it do it?
How can it be avoided?

The explain:

```
+----+-------------+--------------------------------+-------+---------------+-------+---------+------+--------+-------------+
| id | select_type | table                          | type  | possible_keys | key   | key_len | ref  | rows   | Extra       |
+----+-------------+--------------------------------+-------+---------------+-------+---------+------+--------+-------------+
|  1 | SIMPLE      | daniel_table                   | range | cat32         | cat32 | 34      | NULL | 195824 | Using where |
+----+-------------+--------------------------------+-------+---------------+-------+---------+------+--------+-------------+
```

Thanks alot!!